# RSS user feed contains too large image

Tags: bug, images, feed

Recently I have tried to look at [my feed on ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/176217) and saw this:

> [image: unscalled image]

I've already posted a [bug report about  the localization issue with the feed](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4512/176217). About unscaled images I decided to post here, on Meta.SE.

Image in [the original post](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/613856/176217) is scaled.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is the responsibility of SO to scale the images you put in your posts which end up in the RSS feed. The images are taken as-is. How your RSS feed reader renders it is not the problem of SO.

A solution to this problem could be that SO scales all images put in the RSS feed, which could be quite costly for a little gain.

For completeness, this is the actual HTML content from the RSS summary, which shows there is no formatting whatsoever (as it should):

```
<p>На текущий момент стандартных библиотек для графики действительно нет в C++. Нужно использовать сторонние, <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_platform-independent_GUI_libraries#C_.2F_C.2B.2B_packages" rel="nofollow noreferrer">список</a> можно посмотреть на википедии. Но уже сейчас есть соответствующее предложение о добавлении такого функционала и в стандартную часть.</p>

<p>Например, на <a href="https://isocpp.org/std/status" rel="nofollow noreferrer">странице</a> сайта, посвящённого стандартизации C++ есть такая картинка (см. нижний правый угол):</p>

<blockquote>
  <p><a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/euunR.png" rel="nofollow noreferrer"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/euunR.png" alt="2D graphics"></a></p>
</blockquote>

<p>Черновик предложения, озаглавленный как <em>"A Proposal to Add 2D Graphics
Rendering and Display to C++"</em> содержит на текущий момент 227 (!) страниц и доступен по <a href="http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0267r2.pdf" rel="nofollow noreferrer">ссылке</a>.</p>
```

Comment: Just add `max-width: 100%` to images so that they'll look nice, nope?

Comment: No, RSS should not interfere with the layout in my opinion. It creates problems everywhere for those who implement RSS readers. @Qwertiy

Comment: Do you mean rss readers won't accept `<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/euunR.png" alt="2D graphics" style="max-width: 100%;">`?

Comment: That code should be implemented in the RSS reader, not in the source.

Comment: Why do you think they don't?

Comment: Why do you think they do?

Comment: It won't become worse then now if they don't. Actually result will be absolutely the same as now in that case. But if the do, it'll become better. Also I thing they do, as google shows some results about styling rss.